# Is there a way to dynamically get the specific binding of an sap.Table object?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm attempting to write a generic multi-use table filter/sorter. The current solution I have proposed requires being able to know the binding of the text property of a table's row. I can easily get the model that is bound to the table which then I can get all of the attributes of. But this doesn't say anything about the order of how the table displays the data in rows. This would ideally be done at any time. Not on something like row selection.

The closest I can get to getting the attribute is getting the already evaluated binding with this...

```
this.tableObject.getItems()[0].getCells()[0].getText()
```

This returns the actual value of the binding, not the binding itself.

and the path I can retrieve with something like

```
this.tableObject.getItems()[0].getBindingContextPath()
```

which returns the path "/Rowsets/Rowset/0/Row/0"

But this also fails when there is no data in the table.

The table is setup like this

```
<Table id="sap_Responsive_Page_0-content-build_simple_Table-1560756151819" 
width="auto" noDataText="No data" mode="None" showSeparators="All" growing="true" 
growingThreshold="20" growingScrollToLoad="true" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" 
items="{path:'Model>/Rowsets/Rowset/0/Row', templateShareable:true}">
```

Then the rows are setup like this

```
<Text text="{Model>RESOURCE}" width="auto" maxLines="1" wrapping="false" textAlign="Begin" 
textDirection="Inherit" visible="true"/>
```

I expect/want `{Model>RESOURCE}` but instead receive the actual value `TEST`. Is there a different way to get this binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below, to get the binding context of each row.

### Without alias name model

```
this.tableObject.getItems()[0].getBindingContext().getObject();
```

### With alias name model

```
this.tableObject.getItems()[0].getBindingContext("<alias model name>").getObject();
```

### Dynamically get context of each row in a table

We need to attach a **press event**, to get a dynamic binding context of each row in a table.

---

**View**

```
 <Table>
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text=""/>
        </Column>

    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle" type="Navigation" press="onPressItemTable">
            <cells>
                <Text text="{Model>RESOURCE}" width="auto" maxLines="1" wrapping="false" textAlign="Begin" textDirection="Inherit" visible="true"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

**Controller**

```
onPressItemTable : function(oEvent) {
    console.info(`Binding context of selected row: ${oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject()}`);
}
```

Comment: I was able to get results using the alias name model code. This allows me access to the row of evaluated data. Which is helpful in knowing the data, but unfortunately does not give me which column which point of data belongs to.  Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: If you think this is the answer to your main question, you can mark this as the **answer**.

I do not get your point in **'but unfortunately does not give me which column which point of data belongs to'**.  Can you elaborate this?

Comment: The code you have provided returns the object of row[0] of data. So it returns all attributes and data for that row. But this does not show which TableColumn each attribute is binded to. As in, ```{Model>RESOURCE}``` has an attribute in the row of data we retrieved with 
 
**Without alias name model**

    this.tableObject.getItems()[0].getBindingContext().getObject();

but we don't know if that is bound to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. column in the table that displays the data. Thats the part I'm trying to be able to detect. Does that make more sense at all?

Comment: I see. Then your only way to determine the context of row dynamically is to **attach** a **press event** to your table, to determine the context of the selected row. I will edit my answer. Let me know if it is the missing part of my answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer @SystemaAlexzander. Let me know if it helps to your question.